# Why does solidity need a fallback function?

Tags: solidity, fallback-function

I understand when the fallback function is called, but why is it needed at all?
It leaves the way open for a possible reentrancy attack.
It is called when a function of a contract is called that isn't in the contract, why not just throw an exception if that happens?
And when ether is send to a contract that does not have a way of receiving ether, just throw an exception as well?
I can't find anything about why exactly this function is necessary, anyone else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some practical use cases of the fallback function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98589/what-are-some-practical-use-cases-of-the-fallback-function)

Answer (score 2):

One use case is for upgradeable contracts. All function calls are to a "proxy" contract, which contains the storage variables, and since the functions are not defined, the fallback function uses assembly to "delegatecall" to another contract, which calls the appropriate function with the proxy contract's context.

The reason why the fallback function is used is because you may want to add functionality in a future upgrade, and this way it won't have to be defined in the proxy contract.

Both the proxy contract and the upgradeable function contract must have the same storage layout.

OpenZepplin explain it well: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies

Comment: You have a good point, however, in theory one of the main advantages of blockchains is there immutability. So should it even be desirable to be able to use proxy contracts as this basically makes it possible to mutate an existing contract. Moreover is this truly the reason the fallback function was added to solidity?

Comment: It does negate the whole decentralized aspect of the contract, IF one or few addresses have the ability to upgrade the contract. A better practice to make it less centralized, is to use a multisig authentication mechanism, or even better a governance system.